# PHP in_array not behaving as expected

Tags: php, arrays

here is my function:

```
function checkArray($color,$file) {
    $color = trim($color);
    $settings = getSettings($file,1);
    if (in_array($color,$settings)) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

$settings in this context is an array:

```
Array
(

    [0] => Black
    [1] => Blackpol
    [2] => Blk
    [3] => Blue
    [4] => Bronz
    [5] => Bronze
    [6] => Brz
)
```

i have this function looping a few times with the $color parameter changing each time. sample values are "Black","Blue", etc. long story short, checkArray() should return false very few times.

however, it is returning false EVERY time and i cannot for the life of me figure out why. i tried case insensitive searches, trim, printing individual outputs and comparing the strings ("Black" vs "Black")...i am not new to php or arrays but i can't figure out why this would possibly return false. help please!

PRINT_R of $settings (right before the if statement)

```
  Array
    (
    [0] => Black

    [1] => Blackpol

    [2] => Blk

    [3] => Blue

    [4] => Bronz

    [5] => Bronze

    [6] => Brz

    [7] => Bz

    [8] => Cherry

    [9] => Gold

    [10] => Gun

    [11] => Gunmet

    [12] => Gunmetal

    [13] => Pol

    [14] => Poly

    [15] => Quentin

    [16] => Rootbeer

    [17] => Vis
    )
```

VAR DUMP OF $color (right before if statement)

```
string(5) "Black"
```

Comment: Do a `var_dump` of `$settings` and `$color` right before the `if` statement to double check variable values. You may have overlooked something.

Comment: What is in `$settings`. Can you dump it and show us?

Comment: You really should just `return in_array($color, $settings);`

Comment: print_r($settings) outputs 
`Array
(
    [0] => Black

    [1] => Blackpol

    [2] => Blk

    [3] => Blue

    [4] => Bronz

    [5] => Bronze

    [6] => Brz

    [7] => Bz

    [8] => Cherry

    [9] => Gold

    [10] => Gun

    [11] => Gunmet

    [12] => Gunmetal

    [13] => Pol

    [14] => Poly

    [15] => Quentin

    [16] => Rootbeer

    [17] => Vis
)`
vardump $color outputs 
`string(5) "Black"`

Comment: Can you show us this happening in a testcase? [It works for me](http://ideone.com/ipcmh), but I don't have access to your inputs.

Comment: @Alex: Please use backticks to delimit inline code, especially in comments.

Comment: @tomalak, added backticks, sorry bout that.

i can't link you to a testcase but to output the vars i just posted i modified the function as such:

`function checkArray($color,$file) {
 $color = trim($color);
 $settings = getSettings($file,1);
 print_r($settings);
 var_dump($color);
 die();
 if (in_array($color,$settings)) return true;
 else return false;
}`

Comment: @Alex: I would like to see a `var_dump` of `$settings` instead of a `print_r`. Looks like you don't have `string`s in `$settings`, but another datatype.

Comment: @Jürgen, var_dump of $settings is `array(18) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "Black
"
  [1]=>
  string(9) "Blackpol
"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "Blk
"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "Blue
"
  [4]=>
  string(6) "Bronz
"
  [5]=>
  string(7) "Bronze
"
  [6]=>
  string(4) "Brz
"
  [7]=>
  string(3) "Bz
"
  [8]=>
  string(7) "Cherry
"
  [9]=>
  string(5) "Gold
"
  [10]=>
  string(4) "Gun
"
  [11]=>
  string(7) "Gunmet
"
  [12]=>
  string(9) "Gunmetal
"
  [13]=>
  string(4) "Pol
"
  [14]=>
  string(5) "Poly
"
  [15]=>
  string(8) "Quentin
"
  [16]=>
  string(9) "Rootbeer
"
  [17]=>
  string(3) "Vis"
}`

Comment: good lord there's an extra space after everything in settings. sorry guys, i'm an idiot.

Comment: To save me from this exact type of bugs, I echo all my var_dumps/debug echos to a log file, which I `tail -f` it and leave it open all the time in from of me (not on prod though). That way, no white space is hidden from me, ever!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go, you got trailing blanks in the strings. Remove them and you're be fine.

Comment: You're welcome. Happens to me every now and then, too ^^. That's why I dropped usage of `print_r` years ago and only use `var_dump`. Saved me countless times...

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that there are newline characters behind the values in the settings array?

Check your getSettings function, make sure you trim the values there as well.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the `print_r` output suggests that each line contains an extra `\n` linebreak at the end. The use of `$file` also indiciates that you read it from a file. If so, you just need to trim the input.

You can either adapt `getSettings` to read it in using:

```
file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES)
```

Or post-process it in your color test function:

```
$settings = array_map("trim", $settings);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are not mixing encodings.

This *could* be a solution:

```
in_array( mb_strtolower($color, "UTF-8"), $settings)
```